# $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Regularized Least Squares - Strict Convexity Property

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, least-squares, regularization

My objective function that is to be minimized is as follows:

$$\|y-Ax\|_2^2 + \alpha\|Lx\|_1$$

where $L$ is the gradient operator.

Now this problem seems convex because the first term is quadratic and hence convex and the second is a norm so it has to be convex (the triangular inequality), but is it also strictly convex? and why?

Comment: Nobody knows and can help?

Comment: It depends on the data $A$ and $L$, doesn't it?

Comment: Are you looking to solve it or just properties of it?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but Strictly Convex is also related to the Norm of the Space.

Assuming Euclidean Space, the Quadratic Function, Given $ A $ is full rank (Its Null Space contains only the trivial $ \boldsymbol{0} $ vector), is Strictly Convex (And Strongly Convex).

If I remember correctly, a sum of Strictly Convex and Convex Function is a Strictly Convex function.

Comment: What about the quadratic function of a linear function? Strictly convex?

Comment: @LinAlg, What do you mean?

Comment: Suppose $A=O$..

Comment: @LinAlg, For $ A = 0 $ it is not a Quadratic Function of $ x $.

Comment: What if $A \neq O$ but has linearly dependent columns?

Comment: @LinAlg, You are right, $ A $ must be full rank.

Comment: Not exactly. When $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, it needs to have rank $n$. That way, the matrix only has a trivial null space.

Comment: Well, $ {A}^{T} A $ must have no zero Eigen Value.